# Duplicate cookie data with POST request

Tags: post, cookies, tomcat6, mod-jk

An apache server with mod_jk enabled and a tomcat 6 server behind handle requests coming from the clients. We send a POST request to the Server which sends a new POST request internally to another tomcat server (different machine). The result is a string which is sent back to the browser.

Logging the network traffic with tcpdump shows following magic behaviour (we are using jvm routes). This is the POST request from our tomcat server to the other tomcat server:

POST request sending 2 cookie entries:

`cookie: JSESSIONID=9292929292929292929292.abc-xyz`

`<<some other stuff>>`

`Cookie: $Version=0; JSESSIONID=12123121212122122.abc-xyz; $PATH=/`

We are now experiencing that the second SessionId is sent back to the browser, though the browser sent the SessionId named with "cookie" (lower case).

How can it be that the POST request sends 2 cookie information: "cookie" and "Cookie"? Can tomcat be configured to skip that?